# Keycloak Error while authenticating with Microsoft Identity Provider

Tags: java, azure, keycloak

We have configured keycloak version 21.0.1 under Azure load balancer with 2 Linux virtual machines  and it is using the same database. While authenticating using Microsoft Identity Provider it works sometimes and getting error sometimes. Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks you!

When I tried to login to keycloak using Microsoft account we are getting the below error
`2023-05-26 11:33:42,120 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (executor-thread-6) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)`

Comment: Did you check that the certs are in the right path on the linux VMs?

Comment: Yes, I have put all the certs in /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/

Comment: Be sure to check cert file perms and ownership. You may have to restart web server after installing new certificates. Check your logs.